# Filter Jinja list by key existence

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I'm writing an Ansible Template in Jinja, which has the following pattern:

```
# Inventory
[Group1]
vm1 cluster=clusterName

[Group2]
vm2
```

Notice that the second group does not have the property `cluster` defined.

```
# Task Definition
vars:
  potential_seeds: "{{groups.all | map('extract', hostvars) | groupby('cluster') | list}}"
```

This, of course, results in an obvious error:

`"the field 'vars' has an invalid value, which appears to include a variable that is undefined. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'cluster'`

I'm in need of filtering the list in a way that it only groups the dictionaries **that have `cluster` defined**.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`selectattr`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#selectattr) prior to `groupby`:

```
groups.all | 
  map('extract', hostvars) |
  selectattr('cluster','defined') |
  groupby('cluster') |
  list
```

This will select only elements with `cluster` property defined before grouping.